# One-hot encoding in R for big dataframe

Tags: r, xgboost, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to run XGBoost in R and when I reach the step with the one-hot encoding:

```
df_1h <- one_hot(df, cols = "auto", sparsifyNAs = FALSE, naCols = FALSE,
                 dropCols = TRUE, dropUnusedLevels = FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Error in CJ(1:24000, 1:1172779) : 
> Cross product of elements provided to CJ() would result in 28146696000 rows which exceeds .Machine$integer.max == 2147483647
> ```

My dataset consists of approx 220 000 observations and 180 variables. It works if I reduce it to 300 rows for example. Could you please advise me on how to proceed in this case ?

Comment: Try using model.matrix or sparse.model.matrix instead: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/model.matrix

I am not sure it is such a great idea to have so many columns.... Maybe do dimension reduction first.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response ! I have reduced the number of columns to 7. Hence, I managed to increase the number of rows. However, it still says that:                                                                                                             "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.0 Gb".                                            
 Could you please recommend another way to one-hot encode ? 
Sparse.model.matrix still requires the dataset to be one-hot encoded before that, right ?

Comment: No, it simply requires the dataset to have factors rather than characters.

Comment: Fixed the problem, thanks again !

Comment: I will just type it up as an answer to close the thread :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sparse model matrix which does not take up so much memory. It is used by first converting your character variables to factors, and then just running the function.

```
# Some data with characters
df <- data.frame(a=letters, b=c(rep(1,13), rep(2,13)), stringsAsFactors = F)

# Converting characters to factors
df$a <- as.factor(df$a)

# Making model matrix with one hot encoding
library(Matrix)
sparse.model.matrix(b~a, data = df)
```